# How to use json array in order to use each item in the array to use values in a get request ?

Tags: java, arrays, post, jmeter

I have a json array data file (pre-prepared) each item in the json array contain data which I want to be able to use in order to send a request to a server using the json array data file , i know how to be able to send one request after extracting data from the file but I am struggling of getting all the data to send one after another.

I want to imitate the following behavior which I wrote already in java:

```
List<Integer> mtl = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 9, 257, 265});
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.size();i++){

        JSONObject item = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
        int dataFlagType = Integer.parseInt(item.get("DataFlagType").toString());
        if(!(mtl.contains(dataFlagType))){
            sendPushStream(Long.parseLong(m_ap.sid),pid,subsId,item,domain,dnsName,dataFlagType);
        }else{

            lastMessage = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
        }

        Thread.sleep(100);

    }
  Thread.sleep(100);
    sendPushStream(Long.parseLong(m_ap.sid),pid,subsId,lastMessage,domain,dnsName,Integer.parseInt(lastMessage.get("DataFlagType").toString()));
```

where sendPushStream execute the post request itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest organizing your Test Plan as follows:

- [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) (Protocol: `file`, Path: `/path/to/your/file.json`

  - [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) (relevant [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query to extract values and store them into JMeter Variables)
- [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate the Variables coming from the JSON Extractor

  - HTTP Request - to mimic `sendPushStream`

---

Another option is using your Java code from [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler, just make sure you package your helper code as .jar and add it to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

Comment: So what you mean is if I use foreach controller it would extract each item in the array in order without any need to extract each one of the array items?